# Braces around lines and alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, braces

I would like to produce a picture like this

[image]

However, I would like the commas to be aligned.

Usually I would use `alignat` for this, but I don't know how to put braces across lines and `n=1` is precisely between lines.

Here is a MWE using `itemize` and `cases`, but I don't think this will be the right approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item[$n=1$]
$\begin{cases}
(a, b) \\
(cde, f)
\end{cases}$

\item[$n=2$]
$(g, h)$

\item[$n=3$]
$\begin{cases}
(ij, k) \\
(lmno, pq) \\
(rs, tuv)
\end{cases}$

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want all commas from every line to be aligned or just those of one case?

Comment: @Skillmon The commas from all lines. (Otherwise, I think I could just use `array` for each set.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `blkarray`, and, if you want it to look like an enumeration, with the `fleqn`  environment from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut, booktabs, nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{fleqn}
    \[ \begin{blockarray}{l>{(}r@{,{}}l<{)}}
\begin{block}{l\{>{(}r@{,{}}l<{)}}
\BAmultirow{30pt}{$ n = 1 $} & a & b \\
 & cde & f \\
\end{block}
\addlinespace[2ex]
 n =2 & g & h \\
\addlinespace[2ex]
\begin{block}{l\{>{(}r@{,{}}l<{)}}
\BAmultirow{30pt}{$ n = 3 $} & i j & k \\
 & lmno & pq \bigstrut[t]\\
  & rs & tuv \bigstrut[b]\\
\end{block}
    \end{blockarray} \]
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can push the content over to the right one-by-one using a positional marker. This is provided using [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module. It provides `\zsaveposx{<label>}` to store the x-coordinate at the time of placement and `\zposx{<label>}` to retrieve that x-coordinate (in `s`caled `p`oints) which can be used in calculations:

Below I defined `\setshifttarget{<label>}` to define the marker according to which all other `\shiftright{<stuff>}` will be aligned (horizontally). You just need to place this `<label>` at the appropriate spot (in your case, I used `lmno`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,zref-savepos}

\newcounter{str}
\newcommand{\shiftright}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{str}%
  \zsaveposx{str-\thestr}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\zposx{\stshfttrgt}sp-\zposx{str-\thestr}sp}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{$#1$}%
}
\newcommand{\setshifttarget}[1]{\def\stshfttrgt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\setshifttarget{lmno}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[$n=1$]
    $\begin{cases}
    \shiftright{(a}, b) \\
    \shiftright{(cde}, f)
    \end{cases}$

  \item[$n=2$]
    $\shiftright{(g}, h)$

  \item[$n=3$]
    $\begin{cases}
    \shiftright{(ij}, k) \\
    (lmno\zsaveposx{lmno}, pq) \\
    \shiftright{(rs}, tuv)
    \end{cases}$

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Since `zref` uses the `\label`-`\ref` system, you'll have to compile twice with any document changes for the marker positions to settle and have the desired effect.